# Spring context is loaded twice when Spring DispatcherServlet is used from within MeteorServlet of Atmosphere

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to setup a Web application that uses

1. Spring 3.2.x
2. Spring Security 3.x
3. Atmosphere 2.x

I started using this example [SpringMVC-Atmosphere-Example](https://github.com/ghillert/spring-atmosphere-samples/tree/master/spring-mvc-atmosphere-sample).

Using this web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" id="WebApp_ID" metadata-complete="true" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Example Project</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gui-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocket</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useStream</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gui-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/security/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

I get the Spring application-context for the Spring Dispatcher servlet to be loaded twice. Why is it loaded twice and how can I prevent this duplicate context loading?

Comment: I think the meteor you've mentioned here is a different type of meteor or atmosphere?

Comment: @Akshat This appears to be related to this: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere not atmospherejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you have both a `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and a `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` defined within your web.xml, processing the same `spring-context.xml`

`org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` will be invoked when you first deploy your web application and will create a single Spring `ApplicationContext` using /WEB-`INF/spring-context.xml` and `/WEB-INF/security/spring-security.xml`.

Next, the Servlets for your webapp will be created, one of which appears to delegate to a Spring Dispatcher servlet. This will create a new `ApplicationContext` using only `/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml`.

This is why you see your `ApplicationContext` being created twice. To prevent it, use either the `DispatcherServlet` or the `ContextLoaderListener` to create your `ApplicationContext`. Given your need to integrate with another framework, I suspect the easiest option might be to use the `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 1):

Use use-default-filters on applicationContext.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml.

1. applicationContext.xml

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname">

     <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
   </context:component-scan>
2. mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname" use-default-filters="false">
     <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
   </context:component-scan>
3. Remove applicationContext.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml reference from web.xml
4. At applicationContext, import Security-context.xml